# Get values in a javascript array after applying regEx

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, variables, match

Well,

I've a JavaScript variable like below.

```
 var myVar = '<p>This is ~ro..<strong>Yes it is ~hon no?</strong>. happy halloween ~yoo. <strong>~soon</strong> Ho ~no2 ~yes Ho Ho...~jik</p>';
```

I want to get all words after tilde (`~`) in a JavaScript array using regular expression or any other method. In the above case, the array result will be something like below.

```
["ro","hon","yoo","soon","no","yes","jik"]
```

The words can be of any length. Ultimately I want to get all words after `~` in a JavaScript array variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
~([a-zA-Z]+)
```

try this.grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/15

```
var re = /~([a-zA-Z]+)/gm;
var str = '<p>This is ~ro..<strong>Yes it is ~hon no?</strong>. happy halloween ~yoo. <strong>~soon</strong> Ho ~no2 ~yes Ho Ho...~jik</p>';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the regex

`~([a-zA-Z]+)`

see how the regex matches http://regex101.com/r/uL5eX0/1

Comment: This will include `~` as well which OP does not want

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
_list = myVar.match(/~(\w+)/g)

var myList = []

for( i in l){myList.push(l[i].split("~")[1])}

console.info(myList)
```

=======

update:
change regEx to:(thanks for @nu11p01n73R)

_list = myVar.match(/~([a-zA-Z]+)/g)

Comment: small problem with the solution. you cannot use `\w` as the example contains `~no2` of which `no2` will be matched with `\w`, op wants just `no`

Comment: Yer,thanks for @nu11p01n73R 's notice.I really ingore this error.And have update it :)